# How can you see your amount of edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

How can I see how many posts I have edited on Stack Overflow? I'm trying to get 80 edits for that badge but I can't see anywhere how many I've already got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your suggested edits on your profile, under the Activity tab.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2555778/jonan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Plus clicking on one of your suggested edits there lets you see your editor stats, so you can see which of those suggestions were actually accepted (18 in your case).